# The nynphomaniac disease

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, apocalypse, sex, viruses

John is a bright scientist fired from the big corporation ¨ X-santo labs ¨.

John creates a virus to get revenge for being fired.

The virus name is ¨Nymph-01¨

When this virus infects a host via fluid contact the first symptoms that show up are fever and sweating, then hallucinations and extreme arousal, like a perpetual desire to copulate.

The final stage of this disease ends with the loss of memory and complex thinking of its victim, turning it into a crazy sexual predator unable to even talk. The infected have an animalistic behaviour and great strength, basically the loss of human intellect.

This disease has no known cure and affects both men and women regardless of age and is extremely infectious.

**Is this zombie-like virus enough for starting the apocalypse? If not, how can I make it more dangerous without making it lethal?**

Edit: This question isn't a duplicate because the other question is badly written. Please admins delete my other question (the sexy zombie outbreak) and leave this question here. The other question has only 1 answer and was not a good answer and the question is not good too... But I really like this concept.

Comment: I know this won't help, but... I've seen this hentai :P

Comment: @Z.Schroeder i dont watch cartoons.

Comment: @apaul34208 I guess my disease is pretty horrible :D

Comment: Any scientist like John who can create a nymphogenic virus won't get fired. With that amount of skill and knowledge he would be able to create highly profitable organisms of great value to his employers. The creation of such a virus is such a non-trivial exercise in research & development. This will take decades at a minimum. Naming it "Nymph-01" is a bad joke. Naming things is often quirky, the result of happenstance, or given a significant or iconic connection. Like being named after the guy who fired him.

Comment: @a4android If done intentionally it might take decades, if discovered by accident it could take only months; who better to discover something by accident than a careless researcher that can't follow a recipe correctly and therefore deserves to be fired? As for naming, John doesn't have to name it; many diseases are named colloquially after their effects or something else: "Bird Flu" is technically named the H1N1 virus; not "Bird Flu". an unofficial name like "Nympho Flu" would not be implausible, either.

Comment: @AlexMyrmidon Making the virus have early symptoms like fever almost guarantee containment in modern society. Viruses are not reliably transmitted, especially when contact is required; and you are forgetting that most people on the planet love other people, a powerful vector in disease containment: With some publicity, any slight fever in most people will cause them to self-quarantine until they are **certain** they are not about to kill their parents, wives, friends, children or co-workers; and the fever is an immune response that likely occurs long before they are infectious.

Comment: If you want the other question deleted, you'll need to raise a custom flag to diamond mods on that question asking them to delete it. They are unlikely to see a comment edited into this question.

Comment: @Amadeus The OP said "John creates a virus to get revenge", so I assumed it was intentional. Even accidental discovery would take time to ensure it worked as specified. John's revenge would be deflated if the nympho flu only was effective for a day or two. Though global embarrassment might be revenge enough.  Liked your naming suggestions. Its name might be crass and crude -- The F**king Flu -- especially if its victims became sex zombies.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on factors like:

- Can your zombies stay alive? In different ways your zombies could die due to the loss of human intelligence, like basic survival, by gathering food, and finding a shelter, while being infectious, this could really be the point that turns it into a complete apocalypse.
- How will they infect other regions? If we just say the disease was able to infect the region that it is originated from, will it be able to infect different countries and continents, or would the creator of the plague be the one that puts the virus in different regions?
- Is there a final part to the infection? Is there an ending phase to the infection, after death, will there be any consequences, and what could cause death, bullets?
- How physically strong are they? Is it to the point of being invulnerable to bullets, or is it just physically human power of muscles?

All of these are factors that could go into what disease could be an apocalyptic plague, but the question is, if there is no known cure to the disease, how would the creator defend himself, or is it just a crazy suicide throw for a payback?

Answer (score 1):

Sure I'd guess.

The creation of virus like this requires a lot of handwaving (or far-future biotechnology), so there's no reason why the virus shouldn't be able to start an apocalypse.

There are few points that would affect the spreading of the disease:

- Incubation time between the various stages: the longer this takes,
  the more apocalyptic it will become. I think that especially people
  with increased arousal, but not yet obvious insanity, could make this
  virus spread very easily.
- Survivability & (physical) strength in the final stage: if your full zombies forget to eat, they'll die quickly. But if they still have enough brain capability to gather food and stay around, then they could attack and infect more humans.